# Combo Select using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The country and state will be sent as json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "states": [
                "Alabama",
                "Alaska",
                "Arizona"
            ]
        },
        {
            "country": "India",
            "states": [
                "TN",
                "AP",
                "Mumbai"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There will be two select tags (country and state). How do I populate the states based on the country selected?

I am looking for a solution similar to http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html where the `row.data()` returns the *data set* of a particular row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple pure JavaScript way to populate two select boxes via JSON.  In this example, State is dependent upon which Country is selected.

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/wasfd592/

**HTML:**

```
<select id="country">
    <option>Country</option>
</select>
<select id="state">
    <option>State</option>
</select>
```

**JSON Object (assigned to variable d):**

```
var d = {
    "data": [
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "states": [
                "Alabama",
                "Alaska",
                "Arizona"
            ]
        },
        {
            "country": "India",
            "states": [
                "TN",
                "AP",
                "Mumbai"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// First - populate the Country select box from the JSON
for (var i in d.data) {
    var elem = document.createElement("option");
    elem.value = d.data[i].country;
    elem.innerHTML = d.data[i].country;
    document.getElementById("country").appendChild(elem);
}

// Next - add an event handler that will trigger when Country is changed and populate the State box
document.getElementById("country").addEventListener("change", function () {
    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "";
    var country = document.getElementById("country").options[document.getElementById("country").selectedIndex].value;
    if (country === "Country") {
        var elem = document.createElement("option");
        elem.value = "State";
        elem.innerHTML = "State";
        document.getElementById("state").appendChild(elem);
    }
    for (var i in d.data) {
        if (d.data[i].country === country) {
            for (var a = 0; a < d.data[i].states.length; a++) {
                var elem = document.createElement("option");
                elem.value = d.data[i].states[a];
                elem.innerHTML = d.data[i].states[a];
                document.getElementById("state").appendChild(elem);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Using AngularJS would reduce the size of the code no ?

Comment: @NicolasCharvozKurzawa - so adding a large JavaScript library (121KB) to accomplish a simple JavaScript task is the correct answer?  How is adding 121KB reducing code size?

Comment: I was speaking more about leangth of code sorry. Sure this is a great solution. But I was thinking about ng-repeat. Just wanted an advice. No offense :)

Comment: Sure, there are libraries out there that can accomplish this in a few lines, even jQuery would greatly reduce the size of the code block.  However, since the OP is clearly not very familiar with JavaScript, I prefer to give pure-js answers.  I think people should learn JavaScript before working with any libraries.  It helps more in the long-run.  Just my opinion though.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/ox4ykqoL/

**HTML:-**

```
<select id="country"></select>
<select id="states"></select>
```

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var input = {
        "data": [{
            "country": "USA",
                "states": [
                "Alabama",
                "Alaska",
                "Arizona"]
        }, {
            "country": "India",
                "states": [
                "TN",
                "AP",
                "Mumbai"]
        }]
    };

    $.each(input.data, function (index, d) {
        $("#country").append("<option value=\"" + d.country + "\">" + d.country + "</option>");
    });

    $("#country").on("change", function () {
        var selectedCountry = $("#country").val();
        var t = $.map(input.data, function (obj) {
            if (obj.country === selectedCountry) return obj;
        });
        if (t.length != 0) {
            $('#states').empty();
            debugger;
            $.each(t[0].states, function (index, d) {
                $("#states").append("<option value=\"" + d + "\">" + d + "</option>");
            });
        }
    });

    $("#country").change();

});
```